# pygame.error: Couldn't open car.png

Tags: python, file-upload, pygame

Well, this is my first program I write with Pygame. Before opening this thread I read two other thread without any positive result. I almost copied a program to resolve this problem without success. Here is my code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
car = pygame.image.load('car.png')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(car,(x,y))
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
crashed = False
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    gameDisplay.fill(blue)
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(24)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

I thought there could be a problem with directories, but I don't think so. I create a folder in the desktop named "Nuova Cartella" (New Folder in *italian*, and I wrote it in italic ahah) and I put there two files, the first one is the program that I've just post here and the second one is "car.png", that's the image I'd like to load in pygame, of course.
Sorry for my english, I did my best.

Comment: For a start, I would try using the full/absolute path for `car.png`. Also confirm the permission on the file allow the script to access it.

Comment: you have two different objects with the same name `car`, you should fix that too

Comment: Try to `import os` and then `print(os.path.isfile('car.png'))` and `print(os.listdir())`. The former should print `True` if the file exists and the latter prints a list of all files in the directory.

Comment: How do you start the program?

Comment: @skrx just press F5. The Pygame screen does take time to show up though so be patient.

Comment: @PRMoureu thank you I solved the problem! Such stupid error.

Answer (score 1):

A few errors in your code. the most important one was noticed by @PRMoureu. Your definition is called car, and the variable for your image is also called car. Since you created the image variable first, then created a function with the same name you erased the image, and replaced it with the function. So simply change ***'car'*** to something like ***'carImage'*** or anything different than the function name. Also you fill the screen with the color blue, which if you look back you actually haven't defined. after debugging these errors. Here is the code:

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *
pygame.init()
display_width = 800
display_height = 600
black = (0,0,0)
white = (255,255,255)
red = (255,0,0)

gameDisplay = pygame.display.set_mode((display_width,display_height))
pygame.display.set_caption("Game")
clock = pygame.time.Clock()
carImage = pygame.image.load('car.png')
def car(x,y):
    gameDisplay.blit(carImage,(x,y))
x = (display_width * 0.45)
y = (display_height * 0.8)
crashed = False
while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
    gameDisplay.fill(white)
    car(x,y)
    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(24)
pygame.quit()
quit()
```

**But Dont try it just yet!**
From the title it appears that your error is 'couldnt open car.png'
however the issues in your code that i described should give a different error. I find that pretty wierd, and the only explanation to that(considering the fact that the directory is fine and python has permission to access the image) is that your file extension is NOT a png file, but maybe a jpg or something else.

If that's true, then copy the code i have above but change '.png' in

```
carImage = pygame.image.load('car.png')
```

to the correct extension of your image. That should do it.

If none of this works, then i'm afraid this is all the help i can really think of. Maybe more details may help.

I hope this proves helpful anyway. It did work with me, so... Good Luck!